After upgrading to the macOS Sequoia the disk access is too slow for most of the applications
When I logged into the new os, everything was broken, due to - as per my understanding - the problem in the disk access.
First tools that I used were Microsoft Office (Word, Excel, PowerPoint) tools along with the OneDrive. Those seem to all take 15+ minutes to open documents I typically use.
Since those failed, I checked non Microsoft software as well, like the preview app for reaching pdfs, etc.
I suspected from the launch services database, and the fixes that I found for it did not resolve the issue either.
At this point of time, there is no method to "downgrade" back to Ventura for me either. I don’t have a backup.
Symptoms:

When double click a document file some take 15+ minutes to open, both for Microsoft Office apps and other apps like preview
The file selection window either does not open or can not go to some but not all my directories
The same applies when the OneDrive is uninstalled and reinstalled
If I try to open a document from the Spotlight Search, even though it finds the document from the letters that I type in a fair time, again it takes forever to open the file with the associated app.
Interestingly following test through cli works in some folders and does not work in others. The ones it is not working - maybe conincidently - are the ones that OneDrive was tracking. (Though OneDrive app is not active now.)

mkdir real-path
cd real-path
echo "This is a test file" > real-path-test-file.txt
more real-path-test-file.txt
open -a TextEdit real-path-test-file.txt


cd ..
ln -s real-path link-path
cd link-path
ls -ltr real-path-test-file.txt
more real-path-test-file.txt
open -a TextEdit real-path-test-file.txt

So any bit of information is highly appreciated, since this is blocking my business.
Additional tests:

Restart machine > open finder > go to a normal folder > click a word document => opens the document in a fair time
Restart machine > open finder > go to the OneDrive folder > click a word document => Waits "forever"
After the (2), in a new finder go to the same folder of (1) and click the same word document => does not open the document
Recursively copied all the files under the OneDrive folder to a place that OneDrive does not track > restart the machine > click the copy of the same file at (2) => opens the document in a fair time

Observations: Somehow the root folder of the OneDrive is set as /Users/[USER NAME]/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-[SUBSCRIPTION NAME]. And once you try to reach a document there, then all other disk accesses "seem" to be effected.
Because of the tests 2 and 4, it seems the OneDrive structure after the upgrade is possibly the root cause of this problem.

The obvious fix is reset to factory settings and restore from backup - that gets you back to an earlier OS. - If you can't do that immediately get your backups working so you can - if not one day your business will crash. -- However in this case it could just be that spotlight takes a few days to reindex everything.

Since you don’t have a backup, do you want instructions on booting to safe mode to make one now? Your M2 Max hardware should be very fast and will be again once you get a clean erase and clean MS install and the extra hardware needed to preserve your data will be a fraction of the cost for your computer.

It's entirely normal for Sequoia to "Alert" the user to a whole bunch of things when first run.

@bmike, the reason I mentioned like that is to emphisise any app that deal with documents saved on local disk, has access problems for some folders. I can not say what exactly those "some folders" are.

@benwiggy, I have been trying to use the OS since the last 4 days and as of now the frustration did not fade even a bit.

Super details on the timing and that test works great in some local folders and very slow in others. Putting my consultant hat on, I would ask the cost to your business to figure this out vs getting something working. I would buy a fast external SSD and uninstall OneDrive and MS apps and get your local files saved off to free you for an erase and install.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The usual cause of problems when upgrading is very old software that needs to be updated or removed. Often, this takes the form of "background" processes (i.e. not GUI applications) – things like Launch Agents and Kernel Extensions.
Preview is part of the OS itself, and works normally for most people.
Make sure your version of Office is compatible with Sequoia.
Also, make sure that your disk is not full.
I would recommend using EtreCheck, which is a very useful app that produces a report about the state of your Mac. This includes installed software that might affect the running of the OS. Look through everything on the list, and ask yourself: "Is it up-to-date and compatible?" and "Do I need it?".
If you want, you can add the report to your question. (It does not contain any personal identifying information.)

Thanks for the answer @benqiggy. The content of the computer is too valuable for me to risk using a third party application (except the Microsoft's Office tools.) So I am looking for cli commands or Apple's official addresses for the problems.

Definitely invest in two fast external hard drives @MehmetKaplan one thunderbolt 3 to be fast enough to run the old OS externally. The second to get a backup now and then maintain backups going forward to protect your valuable time and documents. So sorry to deliver this news after your problems started. Backups are much easier when the system is healthy. This lets you experiment and work now without waiting for official fix of the internal drive (or having to erase it to get work done this week).

Open "Activity Monitor" to see what is going on. Is what you see in any way realistic? How much RAM do you have? How much network activity? How much disk activity? Apy application doing gazillions of read / write operations?
If you can't find anything that is very obviously wrong and that you can fix, take your computer to tne nearest Apple Store. What you describe is far outside the range of normal behaviour, even normal misbehaviour.

Sounds like 85% idle cpu or higher is what’s reported. Great general troubleshooting steps to get a baseline. I might add, try saving a pages document to /tmp and export as PDF to /tmp and confirm preview and Apple apps work fast from directories where OneDrive isn’t trying to monitor for changes and sync.
